# I have a bad input error in python, any ideas how to fix it?

Tags: python

I have this bad error in put for a game I'm trying to code. It's bare bones at the moment, and I'm trying to code the information for one of the enemies the player fights.

```
class Enemy():
    def __init__(self):
        super(). __init__ (
            self.name = "Goblin" +
            self.healthpoints = 12 + # on this line
            self.damage = 3)
    def isAlive(self):
        return self.hp > 0
```

Comment: You need to provide more information, to make it relevant to us.

Comment: Moreover you don't need to separately write the `super`'s `__init__` in base class and your base class is not inheriting the `super` class

Comment: Well, in your own words, what is the intended purpose of the line where the error occurs? In particular, what is the intent of the `+` signs? What is the class you are inheriting from, and what parameters does its `__init__` expect?

Comment: I would expect you need to separate your arguments to `__init__`. What are the input arguments for the super class? Should it be `super().__init__(self.name=f"Goblin{self.healthpoints+12}", self.damage=3)`? This is assuming name and healtpoints are concatenated, not separate arguments.

Comment: I'd suggest working through some tutorials or textbooks before trying to code something as ambitious as a game (even a simple one); you'll need some fundamental understanding of how the language works before you can express anything complex in it, and this code gives the impression that you're still at the "guess things randomly until the errors stop" stage of understanding.  We all start there but it takes some time focusing on simpler stuff before you get past it.  :)

Comment: `Enemy` only inherits from `object`, and `object.__init__` doesn't take any arguments.

Comment: Thank you all for the help! Sorry I didn't explain the problem better, I'm really new to programming in general, and I have a hard time putting my problems into words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean to do this?

````py
class Enemy():
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "Goblin"
        self.healthpoints = 12
        self.damage = 3
        super().__init__(name=self.name, healthpoints=self.healthpoints, damage=self.damage)
    enter code here
    def isAlive(self):
        return self.hp > 0
    ```
````

Comment: Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

`self.name = "Goblin" +` is a syntax error. You aren't adding anything to `"Goblin"`. The reason it is complaining about the line after is that it is trying to add `self.healthpoints = 12` to `"Goblin"` and you can't add assignment statements.

I think what you want to do is something like this:

```py
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "Goblin"
        self.healthpoints = 12
        self.damage = 3
```

Comment: Thank you for the help!